# Execute simple check function every 10 milliseconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing Nav react component with Filter component inside it. When Component has mounted I start looking at current url and then, if it is not /home I hide Filter component. The code works pretty nice and Nav component changes state when it is needed. The code looks like this:

```
class Nav extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      isHome: true
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(this.checkUrl, 10)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID)
  }

  checkUrl = () => {
    if(!this.state.isHome && this.location === '/home') {
      this.setState({isHome: true})
    }
    if(this.state.isHome && this.location !== '/home') {
      this.setState({isHome: false})
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (

        ...Some other JSX code goes here...

        {this.state.isHome ? <Filter /> : null}

        ...Some other  JSX code goes here...
    )
  }
}
```

The question is: I'm calling the checkURL function every 10 milliseconds, but this function is simple url check. How does this affect productivity of my application? Thank you.

Comment: 10ms seems too short to me. I would change it to 100ms ~ 200ms

Comment: Instead of a timer, any reason you couldn't just check for the change `window.onpopstate`?

Comment: Keith,actually, I have never used window.onpopstate. :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I will move all these logic into render function and let React decide when to re-render Filter component.

I notice that you detemind if the Filter component is showed by this.location. It supposed that "this" here refers to window object, so the location here is the url itself.

Two possibilities here:

First, if you use client-side-router (e.g. react-router, universal-router) to take care of your url. You should use API like history push or some html5 history wrapper to sync your state and url.

Second if you do not use client-side-router. Everytime page reload your whole component will re-render.

Eeither way you do not use this.location to determine the Filter component show or not with a checkUrl-like function.